# How to de-couple MarkLogic clusters safely?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a master cluster and a foreign cluster coupled together. In addition, I've databases replication also enabled for a couple of databases with forest connect by name set to `false`. I'd like to de-couple these two clusters and re-couple them after some days with minimum downtime. Our main activity is to remove some nodes from both master and foreign cluster and so in order to reduce downtimes caused from config. changes I'd like to remove coupling first. Questions.

1. Do I need to remove database replication as well before de-coupling clusters ?
2. Are there REST API's to do that ?
3. What are the xquery API's which into be used ?
4. Where I need to execute the automated script in master or foreign cluster?
5. Any other points I should remember for doing this activity ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than de-coupling the clusters and then re-establishing replication, consider suspending and resuming replication using the [`xdmp:forest-database-replication-suspend()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:forest-database-replication-suspend) and [`xdmp:forest-database-replication-resume()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:forest-database-replication-resume) methods.

In the Admin UI, there are also buttons for
[Enabling, Disabling, Suspending, and Resuming Database Replication](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication/configuring#id_63462)
[image]

Comment: I'd like to avoid downtime. If we suspend coupling then also configurations changes will reflect and updated several times. Also, our motive is removing nodes from clusters and ML manual suggests to remove any coupling before doing that.